# Objects in external json file should be placed in html divs of same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Being new to jquery and javascript, I am looking for a way to insert data from external json file to html code. The data objects in json are named the same as to their corresponding html divs. Also the same should happen at onLoad event of html page.

```js
           var mainObject = {"Main":[{
             "I_Have": [
    {
   "MyMainSavings": {
    "MyMainSavingsTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
     "Rate":""
    },
    "MyMainSavingsBottom": 
    [
     {"Available": "Available","Value": "$4329"},
     {"Clear": "Clear","Value": "$3456"},
     {"Hold": "Hold","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
     },
     {
   "MyEverydayExpenses": {
    "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 600.00",
     "Rate":""
    },
    "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": 
    [
     {"Available": "Available","Value": "$4329"},
     {"Clear": "Clear","Value": "$3456"},
     {"Hold": "Hold","Value": "$7300"}
    ]
   }
     },
     {
   "FavDeposit": {
    "FavDepositTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
     "Rate": "@4.5%"
    },
    "FavDepositBottom": 
    [
     {"MaturityValue": "Maturity Value","Value": "$4009"},
     {"Term": "Term","Value": "$1156"},
     {"MaturesOn": "Matures On","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
     },
     {
   "MyDeposit": {
    "MyDepositTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
     "Rate": "@4.5%"
    },
    "MyDepositBottom": 
    [
     {"MaturityValue": "Maturity Value","Value": "$4329"},
     {"Term": "Term","Value": "$3456"},
     {"MaturesOn": "Matures On","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
      }
         ]
          },   
          {    "I_Owe" :[   
            {"HomeLoans":
     {
       "HomeLoansTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 5,600.00",
       "Rate":"@4.5% floating"
      },  
      "HomeLoansBottom":
      [
       {"Installment":"Installment","Value":"$4329" }, 
       {"Disbursed":"Disbursed","Value":"$3456" }, 
       {"CurrentDues":"Current Dues","Value":"$5000" }
      ]                 
                    }
   },    
   {"Ruby":
     {
       "RubyTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 600.00",
       "Rate":""
      },  
      "RubyBottom":
      [
       {"$6500 Dues":"$6500 Dues","Value":"$4329" }, 
       {"Minimum Due":"Minimum Due","Value":"$3456" }, 
       {"Unbilled":"Unbilled","Value":"$7300" }
      ]                 
                    }
   },
   {"MyOverdraft":
     {
       "MyOverdraftTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 5,000.00",
       "Rate":"" 
      },  
      "MyOverdraftBottom":
      [
       {"Available":"Available","Value":"$4009" }, 
       {"Unclear":"Unclear","Value":"$1156" }, 
       {"Sanc_Limit":"Sanc. Limit","Value":"$5000" }
      ]   
                    }     
   }     
      ]
             }]}
```

```html
         <! DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>first2</title>
             <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsoncss.css">
 
           </head>

            <body>
           <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="MyAccountsLabel">
   <div class="MyAccountsLeft">My Accounts</div>
   <div class="MyAccountsRight"></div>
            </div>
     <div class="LeftSection">
   <div class="LeftSectionTopLeft">I Have (in 4 Accounts)</div>
   <div class="LeftSectionTopRight">+USD 13,700.00</div>
   <div class="MyMainSavings">
    <div class="MyMainSavingsTop">
     <table class="MyMainSavingsTop">
      <tr>
       <td>MyMainSavings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD 7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate"><p></p></div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="MyMainSavingsBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
      
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="MyEverydayExpenses">
    <div class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
     <table class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
      <tr>
       <td>MyEverydayExpenses</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD 7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate"><p></p></div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="MyEverydayExpensesBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="MyDeposit">
    <div class="MyDepositTop">
     <table class="MyDepositTop">
      <tr>
       <td>MyDeposit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD 7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate">@8% Floating Rate</div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="MyDepositBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="FavDeposit">
    <div class="FavDepositTop">
     <table class="FavDepositTop">
      <tr>
       <td>FavDeposit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD 7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate">@8% Floating Rate</div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="FavDepositBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
      </div> 
     <div class="RightSection">
   <div class="RightSectionTopLeft">I Owe (from 3 Accounts)</div>
    <div class="RightSectionTopRight">-USD 33,4500.00</div>
   <div class="HomeLoan">
    <div class="HomeLoanTop">
     <table class="HomeLoanTop">
      <tr>
       <td>HomeLoan</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD$7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate">@8% Floating Rate</div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="HomeLoanBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Ruby">
    <div class="RubyTop">
     <table class="RubyTop">
      <tr>
       <td>Ruby</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD$7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate"><p></p></div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="RubyBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="MyOverdraft">
    <div class="MyOverdraftTop">
     <table class="MyOverdraftTop">
      <tr>
       <td>MyOverdraft</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>x725</td>
      </tr>
       <td>USD$7,600.00</td>
     </table>
     <div class=".InterestRate"><p></p></div>
     <div class="regular">Regular</div>
    </div>
    <div class="MyOverdraftBottom">
     <table class="tablebottom">
      <tr>
       <td>Available</td>
       <td class="right">$7500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unclear</td>
       <td class="right">$750</td>
      </tr>
       <td>Hold</td>
       <td class="right">USD$7,600.00</td> 
     </table>
    </div>
    </div>
       </div>
          </div>
             </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: show us the code which you have tried.

Comment: As of now I havent tried anything. Not sure how to start

Comment: Use a templating JS solution like handlebars. http://handlebarsjs.com/ example: http://jsfiddle.net/tannhu/a9wjbsch/

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a templating solution like handlebars or moustache js.

I've created an example using a sample of your code.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/zrZdNp

```
  <table class="MyMainSavingsTop">
    <tr>
      <td>Account Name</td>
      <td>Account Number</td>
      <td>Balance</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      {{#MyMainSavings}} 
      <td>{{MyMainSavingsTop.AccountName}}</td>
      <td>{{MyMainSavingsTop.AccountNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{MyMainSavingsTop.Balance}}</td>
      <td>{{MyMainSavingsTop.Rate}}</td>
      {{/MyMainSavings}} 
    </tr>
  </table>
```